# Find version of development library from command line?

Tags: application-development, c++, libraries, shared-library, boost

I installed the c++ boost development libraries using Ubuntu software centre. The problem is that it was quite a long time ago and I cannot remember where they are installed nor what version they were. Is there anything I can do from the command line that will tell me what version(s) I have installed on my system?? I know I can do things like

```
gcc -v
```

to get version of an application but is there a similar thing available for libraries? I am using ubuntu 12.04

Comment: What's wrong with `whereis boost`? It returns `/usr/include/boost`. Most library headers are in `/usr/include` their binaries are normally in `/usr/lib`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can quickly find what version or where a library is, even if you do not quite know the title, with dpkg, and, in your case, using boost as the query term:

```
dpkg -l '*boost*'
```

and then query dpkg again with this option for a full list of file locations now you know the name of the file:

```
dpkg -L <'name of lib'>
```

The name of the library may, for example, be libboost1.46-dev.

Answer (score 5):

ldconfig -v requires sudo.

All you really need is to query it, so this will do.

`ldconfig -p | grep [name]`

Answer (score 2):

Use `ldconfig -v` to print libraries and current version number and `grep` to filter your results `ldconfig -v | grep [name]`.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to find the packadge of the lib with `dpkg -S libXYZ.so.N`.

Than do `apt-cache showpkg libXYZ` and the version numbers is shown.